# Change background color of table in google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

[image: Google assistant table view Image]

Is it possible to change the color of table view in google assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cant change the background of the tables on the Google Assistant. As far as i'm aware anyway - there is nothing in their documentation.

Comment: Here's [the official documentation on theming for Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#customizing_your_responses).